# Create cross-platform library to be used from .NET and Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, .net, rust

I feel that it is expected to be possible (to create a library with Rust that can be used from .NET and Objective-C) but after hours of googling I still have not clear picture of how to do so.

Does anyone have such experience (compiling Rust library to be used from Win32/Win64 .NET(P/Invoke), MacOSX, and iOS apps)?

Comment: [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/download) managed to pull it off...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A Rust library which is written with external usage in mind is indistinguishable in ABI from C library, so you can just use FFI tools natural for your language. For Objective-C, I believe, it is sufficient to write a header file which lists functions exposed by the library, and then link the library just as you would link some other C library.

To provide proper C interface, you would need to write `extern` functions which operate on C types. With some annotations these functions will be exposed as C functions callable by any external code which knows how to call C functions. It should work even if you compile your library as a shared object and then load it dynamically (I think you would need it to interoperate with .NET anyway).

For example, this is how an externally available function can be written:

```
#[repr(C)]
struct Foo {
    x: c_int,
    y: c_double
}

#[no_mangle]
unsafe extern fn frobnicate(foo: *const Foo) -> Foo {
    Foo {
        x: foo.x * 2,
        y: foo.y / 2.0
    }
}
```

`#[no_mangle]` disables name mangling, `extern` (equivalent to `extern "C"`) defines calling convention, `#[repr(C)]` forces C field layout to the structure. When a crate containing this code is compiled into a library, `frobnicate` will be exposed as a function symbol, and some other program will be able to call it through corresponding FFI interface.

I think, these links will be helpful for you:

- [Foreign Function Interface](http://doc.rust-lang.org/guide-ffi.html)
- [Writing Unsafe and Low-Level Code](http://doc.rust-lang.org/guide-unsafe.html)
- [Rust's Runtime](http://doc.rust-lang.org/guide-runtime.html) - you will have to start a runtime manually if your Rust library uses some higher-level abstractions in `std`